# loading svg files from s3 into $mdIconProvider - 400 bad request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amazon-s3

I'm using angularjs 1.5.2 and angular material 1.1.0-rc1 for my web application.

I load my svg images from amazon's s3.

I created an $mdIconProvider to store the list of my svg files that I want to load in my page.

```
app.config(["$mdIconProvider", function($mdIconProvider) {
    // Configure URLs for icons specified by [set:]id.
    $mdIconProvider
        .icon('menu', 'https://myalcoholist-tuxin-com.s3.amazonaws.com/svg/menu.svg')
        .icon('add_cocktail','https://myalcoholist-tuxin-com.s3.amazonaws.com/svg/add_cocktail.svg')
        .icon('add_drink','https://myalcoholist-tuxin-com.s3.amazonaws.com/svg/add_drink.svg')
        .icon('admin_cocktails','https://myalcoholist-tuxin-com.s3.amazonaws.com/svg/admin_cocktails.svg')
        .icon('admin_drinks','https://myalcoholist-tuxin-com.s3.amazonaws.com/svg/admin_drinks.svg')
        .icon('admin_pending_images','https://myalcoholist-tuxin-com.s3.amazonaws.com/svg/admin_pending_images.svg')
        .icon('facebook','https://myalcoholist-tuxin-com.s3.amazonaws.com/svg/facebook.svg')
        .icon('google','https://myalcoholist-tuxin-com.s3.amazonaws.com/svg/google.svg')
        .icon('home','https://myalcoholist-tuxin-com.s3.amazonaws.com/svg/home.svg')
        .icon('inventory','https://myalcoholist-tuxin-com.s3.amazonaws.com/svg/inventory.svg')
        .icon('login','https://myalcoholist-tuxin-com.s3.amazonaws.com/svg/login.svg')
        .icon('logout','https://myalcoholist-tuxin-com.s3.amazonaws.com/svg/logout.svg');
}]);
```

when I load my page I see that fetching the main menu svg for example (called 'menu') fails with `400 Bad Request`. and the response from s3 is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>Unsupported Authorization Type</Message><ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName><ArgumentValue>Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjEsInVzZXJHcm91cElkIjoxfQ.M_vAI-WzaxUY47jMK9ahdcvdgpI9UJIhop7ceqaov5g</ArgumentValue><RequestId>CF9968D3244FBC43</RequestId><HostId>kQzEPRTw55tOXaRaOWF2siKcgmQtqgmdTFMpe/yOCBcfB5hEStlqNV5ttdKwJTLDHfaPHGx9yrI=</HostId></Error>
```

now I checked the headers of the https request and i saw the following:

```
GET /svg/menu.svg HTTP/1.1
Host: myalcoholist-tuxin-com.s3.amazonaws.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Origin: https://myalcoholist.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VySWQiOjEsInVzZXJHcm91cElkIjoxfQ.M_vAI-WzaxUY47jMK9ahdcvdgpI9UJIhop7ceqaov5g
Referer: https://myalcoholist.com/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,he;q=0.6
```

so it sends `Authorization` in the header. why?

I have enabled CORS in my s3 bucket with the following configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://myalcoholist.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

I guess to solve this i need to know how to remove the Authorization header from the request... or maybe i'm missing something.

any information regarding the issue would be greatly appreciated.

thank you.

Comment: The way my application's auth is set up, I store and send a JWT with each request after a user becomes authorized. I send this in the header as Bearer. This causes the error from s3. I'm also trying to figure out how to load assets from s3 within the Angular app (directive templates).

I tried adding a condition in an $httpInterceptor that strips the header when 'amazonaws' is in the url, but this doesn't seem to work for asset fetches.

Comment: I was needing to do this for Angular templates so I ended up adding all templates to $templateCache and using them in my app that way. I didn't need to make any requests from my app to s3 that way.